# Can typescript's discriminated union work with conditional types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-systems

Suppose I have the following 3 types:

```
type Apple = {
   type: "apple"
}

type Banana = {
  type: "banana"
}

type Fruit<T extends "apple" | "banana"> = T extends "apple" ? Apple : Banana
```

And I have a generic function as follows:

```
function fruit<T extends "apple" | "banana">(fr: Fruit<T>) {
    if (fr.type === "apple") {
        const element = fr
    }
}
```

Why is `element` still a `Fruit<T>` and not `Apple`? Is there a way to get  discriminated union work with conditional types?